# R shiny does not display datatable

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm making a shiny app that displays the datatable with the results of a database query.
I use an in-house package for retrieving the data and I'm sure this works correctly.

When I want to display the datatable from one of the db's I have no problems, but when I want to display the other the table simply doesn't appear.

I use the reactive function to retrieve the data and renderDataTable() for displaying it. Here is the code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    dataset <- reactive({
    if(input$experiment!=""&!is.null(input$experiment)){
      if(input$db=="db1"){
        data <- querydb1(experimentID=input$experiment)
      }
      if(input$db=="db2"){
        data <- querydb2(experimentID=input$experiment)
      }
    }
  })



  # output table
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    dataset()
  })
})
```

Comment: If you remove the `data<-` from before the `querydb..` statements does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reactive needs to return something. Try this:

```
if(input$experiment!=""&!is.null(input$experiment)){
  if(input$db=="db1"){
    data <- querydb1(experimentID=input$experiment)
  }
  if(input$db=="db2"){
    data <- querydb2(experimentID=input$experiment)
  }
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: thanks this does the trick, still don't understand why db2 worked and bd1 not

Comment: By default R returns the last evaluated statement in an expression. So you don't technically need to call `return` at the end, you could just reference the variable `data`. Since db2 was the last evaluated block, it got returned if the conditional passed. `db1`'s `data` was never the last evaluated statement, so it would never get returned.